# How to use query result to query more in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `User` model, and I have queries like these but it's not working (in Ruby on Rails, you can do these things). Does laravel offer some kind of query that similar to Ruby on Rails?

```
$users = User::where('type', 'user'); // get all the users type == user

// search all users that have 'peter' in their name from previous query result
$users->where('name', 'LIKE', ['%' . 'peter' . '%'])->get(); // get error: Too few arguments to function 
                                                         //Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed
```

Comment: `$users = User::where('name', 'like','%peter%')->get();`

Comment: But this will fetch all users including other type like 'guest', 'mod',..

Comment: I just want to query based on previous result

Comment: you can chnage those function as you need both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$users` becomes a Collection of User Models with this query

```php
$users = User::where('type', 'user')->get();
```

Collections can be filtered in many ways with their own methods.

```
// Simple filter. Returns elements whose 'name' equals 'Peter' or an empty Collection
$filtered = $users->where('name', 'Peter');
// Returns first element whose 'name' equals 'Peter' or null
$user = $users->firstWhere('name', 'Peter');
```

```php
// More complicated filter. filter() lets you do whatever you want. Here, I'm using the Str class helper to get all the elements whose name contains the string 'peter'
$filtered = $users->filter(function ($user, $key) {
    return Str::contains($user->name, 'peter');
});

// If using php > 7.4 you can use shorthand closures
$filtered = $users->filter(fn($user, $key) => Str::contains($user->name, 'peter'));
```

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers

Comment: Thank you! The last one, the shorthand closures one for php > 7.4 works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
$users = User::where('type', 'user'); // get all the users type == user

// search all users that have 'peter' in their name from previous query result
$users->where('name', 'LIKE', '%peter%')->get();
```

Comment: Still get this error: `TypeError: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$users->where('player', 'like', '%'. 'ryan' .'%')->get();
```

nested where

```
$users->where('type', 'user')->where('player', 'like', '%'. 'ryan' .'%')->get();
```